# ASP.NET MVC4 IHubContext chunking errror in Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

In my project the server pushes updates to the clients via SignalR. This normally works well, but occasionally in Chrome I get the following error:
[image]

I have seen some suggestions about the connection being prematurely closed, or the headers not being set appropriately, but I am at a loss as to how I can set this in my code.
The below method (server code) is an example of how I send updates to the client:

```
 public void UpdateHubClientsUpdateAvailability(Availability availability)
    {

        if (availability.Deleted)
        {
            IHubContext hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Hubs.UpdateHub>();
            LogClients(hub.Clients, "UpdateHubClientsUpdateAvailability");
            string update = GetClientUpdateString(availability, false);
            hub.Clients.All.removeAvailability(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(update));
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateHubClientsAppearanceUpdateAvailability(availability);
        }
    }
```

removeAvailability is a client side JavaScript method.
Does anyone know how I could change the above code to stop getting this problem?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically a connection error.

1. Make sure that your physical connections are good.
2. That there are no firewalls or antivirus software interfering with your communication.
3. Do a tracert from your client to your server and see if you are getting timeouts.
4. Check your network tab in chrome to be sure that your requests are getting through.
5. You can also turn on the signalr logging and see if you are losing connection to your hub frequently and getting a lot of onReconnected or disconnected events firing in the browser.
6. Lastly,  make sure that if you are doing cross origin requests that CORS is configured properly.